# Cookies Not Found with Python Script

Tags: python, cookies

I wrote this to try to get cookies from my browser on python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print('Content-type: text/html\n')

def getCookies():
    import os

    if 'HTTP_COOKIE' in os.environ.keys():
        cookie_set = os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE']
        cookies = cookie_set.split(';')
        for acookie in cookies:
            print(acookie.strip())
    else:
        print('No cookies found')


getCookies()
```

But everytime, it says "cookies not found", even though I can see the cookies on Firefox. What might be causing the problem.

I would great appreciate help! I've been stuck on this for 4 hours and this is my first time on stack overflow.

Comment: How and where do you invoke this script? `os.environ` simply contains a dictionary of your environment variables and your browser is not going to change those.

Comment: What do you mean by environment variables?

Comment: Under windows all kind of stuff like the PATH settings. Under Linux probably the same like things as %PATH%. You can check in a one-liner what it returns: `for k,v in os.environ.items(): print(k,v)`